# Why isnt svelte conditional class not applied on load?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, svelte, sveltekit

**Background information**

I am trying to learn Sveltekit and wanted to create a dashboard together with Bootstrap tab components. For this I wanted to use `<buttons>` instead of `<a>` tags, because I don't want to forward to different routes. Instead I want to change the contents of the page depending on the selected button, that's why I use buttons.

I also initialise the first tab component, to easily assign the first component the active class.

I tested before with different components, that bootstrap is correctly included in my project.

I am using the latest SvelteKit version (to this day) and Bootstrap 5.3.

**My problem**

My problem is, that on load the first tab component doesn't get the active class, as it should. I tried to use e.g. onMount functions to reassign the first active class, but all that didn't work.

Below is my code, if anybody can help me thanks a lot. Please ask any questions, if there is any information missing regarding my question.

```
<script>

    const firstTabItem = {
        id: "0",
        title: "Home"
    };

    const tabItems = [
        {
            id: "1",
            title: "About us"
        },
        {
            id: "2",
            title: "Products"
        },
        {
            id: "3",
            title: "Contact"
        },
    ]

    let currentTab = 0;

</script>

<h1>Dashboard</h1>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <button class="nav-link" class:active={firstTabItem.id === currentTab} on:click={() => {currentTab = firstTabItem.id}}>{firstTabItem.title}</button>

    {#each tabItems as item}
        <button class="nav-link" class:active={item.id === currentTab} on:click={() => {currentTab = item.id}}>{item.title}</button>
    {/each}         
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The types don't match. `currentTab` is a number while all other IDs are strings.

If you use strict equality (`===`), which requires the type to be the same, the comparisons will always be `false`. Would recommend just making everything the same type.

(Loose equality (`==`) would also work but would not recommend comparing things of different types in general.)

Comment: You dont know how long Ive been looking at the code and thinking to myself, that this is so simply that there cant be a mistake. Thank you very much